# duplicate entry: zzc.class

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, dependencias

Buen dia!! estoy usando firebase y desde que use sus dependencias me sale el siguiente error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Customer:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class
```

Estas son mis dependencias

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':pinnedlibrary')
    compile project(':countrylist')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile 'com.mobapphome.library:mah-encryptor-lib:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.10@aar'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0'
    compile 'com.dev.sacot41:scviewpager:0.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'me.wangyuwei:LoadingiVew:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    //ORM
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile project(':fliclib')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    //okhttp
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    //event bus
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Ojalá puedan orientarme. muchas gracias!!

Comment: hmm al parecer una de esas librerías está usando la lib gms de google , de que trata   compile project(':pinnedlibrary')
    compile project(':countrylist') ?

Comment: Gracias amigo por apoyar, se soluciono al actualizar las dependencias gms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se resolvió actualizando las dependencias de gms a:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, esto me funciono a mi.
Gracias

Comment: De hecho este problema, que en realidad es un BUG, fue corregido desde la versión 11.0.1, https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases